# Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<User>

Tags: apex, visualforce

i am not sure why this error is shown,when i am mapping a new ID against and ID field.

Here i am trying to achieve this requirement :  Want to do this for existing user. So i have queried the set of users [into list variable user}for which now I want to update the ManagerId with a new Id. Which you can see it in : for loop i am trying to update the set of users in the list with updated ManagerId and then adding it to TrsfrMgr list. But that assignment itself isnot working.

Can someone please help!!

```
List<User> FromMgrId ,ToMgrID ;
ToMgrID  = [select Id from User where name=: ToMgr] ;
for (User a : user)
          {
             system.debug('OLDMgrId' + a.ManagerId);
              a.ManagerId = (ID) ToMgrID.Id;
              TrsfrMgr.add(a);
          }
```

Comment: That is not even close to valid Apex. Please articulate more specifics about what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to assign one Id value to another. You should create a new user, initialize it with the ToMgrId.Id and then add it to the TrsfrMgr list.

Comment: hi @codeinprogress : yes but i want to do this for existing user. So i have queried the set of users  [into list variable user}for which now I want to update the ManagerId with a new Id. WHich you can see it in :  for loop i am trying to update the set of users in the list with  updated ManagerId and then adding it to TrsfrMgr list.  But that assignment itself isnot working.

Comment: Can you do something like this.  Id tomgrId  = [select Id from User where name=: ToMgr limit 1].Id ;   and then in your for loop, a.ManagerId = tomgrId;

Answer (score 1):

There error is in the following line

```
a.ManagerId = (ID) ToMgrID.Id;
```

The ToMgrID is a List and you are trying to access the ID field from it. You would need to get the user record from the list and then access the ID field.

Comment: yeah i know,but i was unable to figure out why it cant take ToMgrID.Id to assign it to another Id field.  But now sorted with the resolution given by codeinprogress. :) bit strange though : as i understand ToMgrID = [select id user where name =:tomgr limit 1]. id  is same as  ToMgrID = [select id from user where name =: to mgr limit 1] then access Id by ToMgrID.id ,but that dint work :/

Comment: The reason is the difference in the data type. When you were retrieving using Name, you were defining ToMgrID as a List<User>. Whereas in the suggestion by codeinprogress, the ToMgrID was defined with data type as Id. In your previous code ToMgrID[0].Id would have worked as it would use the first record from the list.